# How to add existing folder in project/solution

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I have many source files organized in folders and I need to integrate them into my solution. However there is no option to transfer all these folders into my project. Only file transfer (by drag and drop or by choosing add existing item) is possible. Is it possible to transfer the folder together with the files in it?

Comment: Everybody says to click on Show All files and then you will see the folders after which you have to right click on them and choose "Include in Project". The problem is that I do not see foders when I click on Show all files. I see only files.

Comment: Ok, now it is clear, you should position your folders in the folder where the project files are and not where the solution is...

Comment: But the problem still persists, if you select the folders and say to add them to the project, it adds files instead of folders (with the whole subdirectory structure and files)

Comment: Are you doing this with full visual studio or the Express version?

Comment: No, the worst thing is that I am usung the expensive one: Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate

Comment: I think that some option should be activated somewhere.

Comment: And I tried to do everything possible, starting VS in administrator modus, trying the whole thing in Debug/Release Mode, nothing helps, the VS just traverse recursively all the subdirectories, picks header and source files and puts them into "Header Files" and "Source Files" folders respectively.

Comment: Ok, this is really strange, I just created an empty C-Sharp project and there it works. But with an emptry Visual C++ Project it does not work. Is Microsoft behind it???